# ¿Cómo puedo insertar una imagen de fondo en body con css de RAILS 7?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-5

He estado intentando insertar una imagen de fondo en el Aplication.css de RAILS7, trabajo con Bootstrap 5, mi línea de código es la siguiente:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: var(--bs-body-font-family);
  font-size: var(--bs-body-font-size);
  font-weight: var(--bs-body-font-weight);
  line-height: var(--bs-body-line-height);
  color: var(--bs-body-color);
  text-align: var(--bs-body-text-align);
  background-color: var(--bs-body-bg);
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-image: url("../images/fondo.jpg");
}
```

Alguien tiene alguna idea de como se debe realizar el llamado a la imagen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tu imagen está en la  ruta `app/assets/images/fondo.jpg` prueba esto:

```
background-image: url(<%= /assets/my-image.jpg' %>)
```

En esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63549592/14395607) de StackOverflow en inglés, puedes encontrar más información.

Comment: Efectivamente, esa era la solución amigo muchas gracias